# W3WP Crash and how to restore application

Tags: crash, w3wp

I have a customer where our application crashes sometimes without a meaningful reason. 
So I would like to know what we can do, if such a failure occurs.

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x5315a05a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d
Faulting process id: 0x66f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d06782712abe50
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dfdc8ac6-d414-11e4-96b8-00155dcc2300
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The step by step [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/03/20/debugging-a-net-crash-with-rules-in-debug-diag.aspx?Redirected=true) how to debug randomly crashing w3wp

Comment: The link is dead